# Oracle CREATE TYPE statement before CREATE PROCEDURE not working

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to create an Oracle array with the `CREATE TYPE` command. But I am getting an error if I run the statement before a `CREATE PROCEDURE` call.

I am using Oracle 12g

This is the code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE arr AS VARRAY(200) OF VARCHAR2(10);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_createList(items arr DEFAULT NULL) AS
...
END;
/
```

But I get this error after the `CREATE TYPE` statement

> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE"

Comment: why do you do drop/create or replace? create or replace should be sufficient

Comment: @T.S. good catch, this doesn't affect the problem though

Comment: @Gauravsa Yes, if you have something to share, please link it. It's not an issue with using a `/` because it is plain SQL, no PLSQL

Comment: In fact, I think it is about `/`. *"because it is plain SQL"* - no, this is not SQL at all. This is DDL

Comment: @T.S. It seems like you are correct, my mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this: there is a / missing after the type

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE arr AS VARRAY(200) OF VARCHAR2(10);
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_createList(items arr DEFAULT NULL) AS
...
END;
/
```

Comment: Why is the `/` after a command needed when there is no PL/SQL present?

Comment: @CupofJava `/` is not a pl/sql construct. This is a processor command to execute all above. Its like `go` in sql server. And since oracle can't execute sql;sql; .. you get the idea